# SMA crossover Filter for overlap signal pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

i have a pandas dataframe

```
time price buy sell
1    1     0   0
2    1     buy 0
3    1     buy 0
4    1     buy 0
5    1     0   sell
6    1     0   sell
```

how can i archeive like this

mean filter for overlap signal like continuous buy, buy

```
time price buy sell  signal
1    1     0   0     0
2    1     buy 0     buy
3    1     buy 0     0
4    1     buy 0     0
5    1     0   sell  sell
6    1     0   sell  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use boolean mask:

```
m1 = df['buy'].eq('buy') & df['buy'].shift().eq('0')  # buy signal
m2 = df['sell'].eq('sell') & df['sell'].shift().eq('0')  # sell signal

df['signal'] = '0'
df.loc[m1, 'signal'] = 'buy'
df.loc[m2, 'signal'] = 'sell'
```

Output:

```
>>> df

   time  price  buy  sell signal
0     1      1    0     0      0
1     2      1  buy     0    buy
2     3      1  buy     0      0
3     4      1  buy     0      0
4     5      1    0  sell   sell
5     6      1    0  sell      0
```